# Node save slow with a field containing lots of paragraphs

Tags: 8, paragraphs

I have a node (which uses revisions) that has a [Paragraph](https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs) field. It has around 80 Paragraphs referenced to it. When I save the node programmatically it's very slow. It seems like the slow down is happening in the preSave() of the Paragraph field. I'm wondering if every referenced Paragraph is being loaded when the node is being saved? And if so is this normal functionality?

Could it just be bad design by myself that I created a node that has a field with 80+ Paragraphs referenced to it? Or is it legitimate to do it this way?

Comment: This is the very basic concept of Entity Reference Revisions (ERR) fields like Paragraphs: When you save the parent entity, and new revision of all child entities is created. If you don't want this, don't use Paragraphs, use a normal "entity reference" instead.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a known issue and currently being discussed on [drupal.org](https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs/issues/2935134). Have a look at the latest comments there, maybe something in there you can tweak.